# BigQuery; extract numbers only from a string

Tags: split, extract, google-bigquery

my data looks like a 1x1000 vector with variable number of inputs in a like. sometimes it is just age but sometimes they add weight and state ID.

```
85 age
15 age; 68 Weight
25 age; 80 Weight; 02 Alaska
72 Weight; 50 Wyoming
```

What I would like to get as output are just numbers - i.e.

```
85
15 68 
25 80 02 
72 50
```

I don't succeed that much using SPLIT since that gives me over 2000 lines back instead of 1000. So I don't know how to do it.
Unless SPLIT could be combined and tell me how many information points were there before split. I.e.

```
85    1
15    2
68    2
25    3
80    3
```

etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("25 age; 80 Weight; 02 Alaska",'[^0-9 ]','')
```

Read more about [Regular Expression functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness - this is how you could use SPLIT to get the result with counts of information points before split:

```
select left(xs, 2), count(xs) within record from(
select split(x, ";") xs from 
(select "85 age" as x),
(select "15 age; 68 Weight" as x),
(select "25 age; 80 Weight; 02 Alaska" as x),
(select "72 Weight; 50 Wyoming" as x))
```